# How to split string in C#

Tags: asp.net, string

I have a string and I want to get this  sub string. [  10:30 to 11:30  ] .

I don't how to do it.
strong text

> string a = "This is my string at -10:30 to 11:30-";

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` to get the first and the last dash.

```
var firstDash = a.IndexOf("-");
var lastDash = a.LastIndexOf("-");

var timePeriod = a.Substring(firstDash + 1, lastDash - 1);
```

That should be it. Play with +1 and -1 in case I missed where the reading starts for the substring method.

You might also want to check for the result of `firstDash` and `lastDash`. If the value for any of them is -1 then the target string or character was not found.

Comment: Thanks Husein Roncevic. Its great.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired string using Regex. Try below code to do that.
Regex example: [Regex Test Link](https://regex101.com/r/luC10T/1)

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        string a = "This is my string at -10:30 to 11:30-";
        string pat = @"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\sto\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";

        // Instantiate the regular expression object.
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
        Match m = r.Match(a);
        if(m.Success){
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
        }      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the simplest code. The regex is same as the above.

```
String result = Regex.Match(a, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s*to\s*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").ToString();
```